SQLite in iOS with Maui crashes when the app is published on the store
In my NET8 MAUI application, I use SQLite and here are the packages I added to the project.
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Data.Sqlite" Version="8.0.6" />
<PackageReference Include="sqlite-net-pcl" Version="1.9.172" />
<PackageReference Include="SQLitePCLRaw.bundle_green" Version="2.1.8" />
<PackageReference Include="SQLitePCLRaw.provider.sqlite3" Version="2.1.8" />

The application reads the database quite often. In debug, the application runs normally without errors. When I published the application on the Apple store, when the app reads the database, the application crashed immediately. I can see the error in the AppCenter

SIGABRT: Attempting to JIT compile method '(wrapper delegate-invoke) void System.Action`2<LanguageInUse.Domain.Dictionary, System.DateTime>:invoke_callvirt_void_T1_T2 (LanguageInUse.Domain.Dictionary,System.DateTime)' while running in aot-only mode. See https://docs.microsoft.com/xamarin/ios/internals/limitations for more information.

The full error is this one
SQLite.FastColumnSetter.<>c__DisplayClass2_0`2[[LanguageInUse.Domain.Dictionary, LanguageInUse, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null],[System.DateTime, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]].<CreateTypedSetterDelegate>b__0(Object o, sqlite3_stmt stmt, Int32 i)
SQLite.SQLiteCommand.<ExecuteDeferredQuery>d__12`1[[LanguageInUse.Domain.Dictionary, LanguageInUse, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]].MoveNext()
System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[LanguageInUse.Domain.Dictionary, LanguageInUse, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]..ctor(IEnumerable`1 )
System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[Dictionary](IEnumerable`1 )
SQLite.SQLiteCommand.ExecuteQuery[Dictionary]()
SQLite.TableQuery`1[[LanguageInUse.Domain.Dictionary, LanguageInUse, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]].ToList()
SQLite.AsyncTableQuery`1[[LanguageInUse.Domain.Dictionary, LanguageInUse, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]].<ToListAsync>b__11_0(SQLiteConnectionWithLock conn)
SQLite.AsyncTableQuery`1.<>c__DisplayClass2_0`1[[LanguageInUse.Domain.Dictionary, LanguageInUse, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null],[System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[LanguageInUse.Domain.Dictionary, LanguageInUse, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]], System.Private.CoreLib, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]].<ReadAsync>b__0()
System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[[System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[LanguageInUse.Domain.Dictionary, LanguageInUse, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]], System.Private.CoreLib, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]].InnerInvoke()
System.Threading.Tasks.Task.<>c.<.cctor>b__281_0(Object obj)
System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunFromThreadPoolDispatchLoop(Thread , ExecutionContext , ContextCallback , Object )
System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunFromThreadPoolDispatchLoop(Thread , ExecutionContext , ContextCallback , Object )
System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecuteWithThreadLocal(Task& , Thread )
LanguageInUse.Persistence.LIUDatabase.GetDictionariesForSearchAsync(String username, String search)
LanguageInUse.ViewModels.DictionaryListViewModel.<Init>b__13_0(Object s, PopupOpenedEventArgs e)
System.Threading.Tasks.Task.<>c.<ThrowAsync>b__128_0(Object state)
Foundation.NSAsyncSynchronizationContextDispatcher.Apply()
ObjCRuntime.Runtime.ThrowException(IntPtr )
UIKit.UIApplication.UIApplicationMain(Int32 , String[] , IntPtr , IntPtr )
UIKit.UIApplication.Main(String[] , Type , Type )
LanguageInUse.Program.Main(String[] args)

I tried in debug and release on my real devices and the application is working. I saw on GitHub this quite similar bug but it is 2 years old. In this post, they recommend downgrading the SQLite version - 2 years ago - or building with these settings.

Also, I saw this other issue always on GitHub that is more recent. They said to use in Release for iOS this settings
<UseInterpreter>true</UseInterpreter>
<MtouchInterpreter>-all</MtouchInterpreter>

I don't want to send more updates to the Apple Store with a broken app. Do you face the same issue? How can I fix the problem?

There are numerous workarounds mentioned in the GitHub issue.  Have you tried all of them?  Do you know which specific queries are causing the crash?

Have you tried downgrading SQLite? Also, what is the iOS version of the device you are deploying on?

I haven't tried to downgrade SQLite. The iOS version is 17.5.1

Do you encounter this problem on other versions of iOS devices? In addition, similar issues on GitHub also suggest adding <UseInterpreter >true</UseInterpreter> to the .csproj file.

@Enrico did you manage to solve this issue?
